# C# WPF Gui Checkbox Name as array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, checkbox

I created with WPF some CheckBoxex. Its important for my program that i can access my Checkboxes with an array.

eg.

### iGPIO[1].IsChecked

```
 <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <CheckBox Name="iGPIO[0]" Content="GPIO 1"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Name="iGPIO[1]" Content="GPIO 2"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 3"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 4"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 5"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 6"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 7"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 8"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 9"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 10"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 11"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 12"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 13"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 14"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 15"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 16"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 17"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 18"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 19"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 20"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 21"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 22"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 23"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 24"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 25"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 26"/>
                <CheckBox Content="GPIO 27"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do you need to access the checkbox objects themselves or perhaps just the value of the checkboxes, i.e. `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an ListBox to group checkboxes and DataTemplate

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding TheText}" 
                     Tag="{Binding TheValue}" Checked="CheckBoxZone_Checked"/>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach for doing that.

First of all, give your StackPanel a Name property like "myStackPanel".

Then add this Using on top, for querying through objects:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And do as the following:

```
// Get all available checkboxes in the StackPanel's children.
var checkBoxes = myStackPanel.Children.OfType<CheckBox>();

for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(checkBoxes[i].Content + ": " checkBoxes[i].IsChecked.ToString());
    // GPIO 1: true
    // GPIO 2: false
    // etc...
}

// Get first checkbox state
MessageBox.Show(checkBoxes[0].IsChecked.ToString());
```